# SQLite3 Match on VIEW?

Tags: view, sqlite, virtual, match

So I am attaching multiple databases, then creating a TEMP VIEW which combines all the virtualTables from the various databases as such.

```
theDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TEMP VIEW virtualView AS SELECT * FROM Virtual_Sites UNION SELECT * FROM db1.Virtual_Sites UNION SELECT * FROM db2.Virtual_Sites");
```

Is it possible to use the MATCH query on this VIEW?

```
theDatabase.rawQuery(SELECT * FROM virtualView WHERE all_text MATCH 21033, null)
```

I am currently getting this error.

```
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = statement aborts at 46: [SELECT * FROM virtualView WHERE all_text MATCH 21033] unable to use function MATCH in the requested context, db=xxx

exception: SQL logic error or missing database; query: SELECT * FROM virtualView WHERE all_text MATCH 21033
```

I have read that creating VIEW's in this way will not inherit the underlying tables indexes, is this why I am unable to do a MATCH? If so any work arounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MATCH` works only directly on virtual tables that implement this operator, not on views.

You will have to rewrite all your queries to use `MATCH` on the individual tables, and to combine those results with `UNION ALL`.

Alternatively, copy the data of all your tables into one single temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found. VIEWS are in-efficient when combining multiple databases/tables as they loose their underlining indexes once they contain more than 2 tables.

**ATTACH**

```
String newDbPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
theDatabase.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '" + newDbPath + "' as db1;");
```

**The in-efficient way**

```
Create VIEW
theDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TEMP VIEW view1 AS SELECT * FROM Sites_hsf UNION SELECT * FROM db1.Sites_hsf UNION SELECT * FROM db2.Sites_hsf;");

Query VIEW
sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM view1 s INNER JOIN view2 con ON s.site_uid = con.site_uid AND con.ap_active = 1 WHERE s.site_uid = 1114331";
```

Execution Time
16281 Milliseconds

**The efficient way**

```
sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Sites_hsf s INNER JOIN Connections_hsf con ON s.site_uid = con.site_uid AND con.ap_active = 1 WHERE s.site_uid = 1114331 " +
                "UNION ALL " +
                "SELECT * FROM db1.Sites_hsf s1 INNER JOIN db1.Connections_hsf con1 ON s1.site_uid = con1.site_uid AND con1.ap_active = 1 WHERE s1.site_uid = 1114331 " +
                "UNION ALL " +
                "SELECT * FROM db2.Sites_hsf s2 INNER JOIN db2.Connections_hsf con2 ON s2.site_uid = con2.site_uid AND con2.ap_active = 1 WHERE s2.site_uid = 1114331";
```

Execution Time
4 Milliseconds

---

MATCH using CL.'s answer of UNION ALL

```
sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Virtual_Sites_hsf WHERE all_text MATCH '40227' " +
                "UNION ALL SELECT * FROM db1.Virtual_Sites_hsf WHERE all_text  MATCH '40227'" +
                "UNION ALL SELECT * FROM db2.Virtual_Sites_hsf WHERE all_text  MATCH '40227'"
```

---

Hopefully this helps someone.